# Parachute characteristics of the Viking mission

Tags: mars, viking

I'm looking for the characteristics (diameter, coefficient of drag, altitude and velocity of deployment) of the parachute used by the Viking descent module on Mars.

I found in this document [1] that the parachute is opened between 6096 and 7620 meters above the ground level.

In this document [2], we can read that the parachute diameter is 16 m.

How reliable are these information? It is for a reentry simulation.

[1]: https://ntrs.nasa.gov/archive/nasa/casi.ntrs.nasa.gov/19810001592.pdf p.241

[2]: https://www.jpl.nasa.gov/news/fact_sheets/viking.pdf p.4

Comment: How reliable are the NASA documents? I doubt you will find anything more reliable.

Comment: That's what I thought but on this document by also the NASA we can see that, page 8, the Viking parachute has a diameter of 11.5 meters : https://ntrs.nasa.gov/archive/nasa/casi.ntrs.nasa.gov/20060028185.pdf